# Fixing my breadcrumbs.php file - It is ignoring parts of the URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to use this breadcrumb script to generate links to parent URLs on my site.

I successfully have it linking back on pages that are only one click away from the homepage, however it is not working for URLs that have gone one step deeper into the website.

Here is the code:

```
<?php if( $breadcrumbs === TRUE ): ?>

    <?php

        // This function will take $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and build a breadcrumb based on the user's current path
        function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
            // This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
            $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

            // This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
            $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

            // Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
            $breadcrumbs = Array("<a href=\"$base\">$home</a>");

            // Find out the index for the last value in our path array
            $last = end(array_keys($path));

            // Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
            foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
                // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
                $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.html', '.php', '_', '-'), Array('', '', ' ', ' '), $crumb));

                // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
                if ($x != $last)
                    $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$base$crumb.html\">$title</a>";
                // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
                else
                    $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
            }

            // Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)
            return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
        }

    ?>

    <p id="breadcrumbs" class="breadcrumbs"><?= breadcrumbs(' > ') ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't believe you will need a link to a live version, I think there just needs to be a for each loop added in to scale this up.

**It successfully writes out the full breadcrumb, it is not represented in the URL created within the anchor.**

Comment: `$crumb` is the respective path segment only, and you are outputting that inside your link. You need to store the concatenated previous path segments in a helper variable.

Comment: @misorude - Great to hear from you again! Thanks for jumping in. I will have a look at implementing that. Any further pointers or examples you could show me? Thanks, Jason

Comment: What is your actual URL structure? Just wondering, since you are appending `.html` at the end here. If you had a page `/foo/bar/baz.html`, would that mean that `/foo/bar.html` and `/foo.html` also exist? Otherwise, you can’t append the `.html` to all links in the breadcrumb trail, but would need to differentiate between those cases.

Comment: @misorude - all pages within the breadcrumbs are linkable. I have set it so they are parent pages. Where all pages have the .html extention (if it is the last in the breadcrumb trail). So /foo/bar/baz.html, /foo/bar.html and /foo.html all exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing here is that you need to treat the link text and the link href differently. For the text, you only want to output the name of the current path segment - `bar` for the second link to generate for my `/foo/bar/baz.html` example; but the path in the href must not only be `bar` (or `bar.html`), but the previous segments need to be kept here as well. This is easiest with a helper variable, that you initialize as an empty string, and then append `/` and the current path segment in every iteration. (By putting the slash first, you can still append the `.html` at the end without problems; if you did it the other way around, and your helper variable contained `foo/bar/`, you would get a wrong path `foo/bar/.html`)

Since this relative path then starts with a `/` already, you should remove the trailing `/` from your $base URI to not get double slashes here - or you leave that base URI out completely, a relative link starting with `/` always points to the domain root anyway.

Untested, but something like this:

```
// Build the rest of the breadcrumbs

// helper variable to assemble the path, initialized as empty string
$tempPath = '';    

foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
    // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
    $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.html', '.php', '_', '-'), Array('', '', ' ', ' '), $crumb));

    // append / and current path segment
    $tempPath .= '/' . $crumb;

    // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
    if ($x != $last)
        // insert this temporary path into link href, and add .html
        $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"$tempPath.html\">$title</a>";
    // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
    else
        $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm. It does work. Thank you so much, I actually understand what you have done - so thanks for teaching too <3

Comment: Perfect :-) Happy to help.